# Yii: how to use different database for a particular query when using activerecord

Tags: php, yii

Country.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Country extends ActiveRecord
{
}
```

Now I am using the above class to query the Country table using the default db configuration

```
use app\models\Country;

// get all rows from the country table and order them by "name"
$countries = Country::find()->orderBy('name')->all(); // this line uses default db configuration
```

protected/config/main.php

```
return array(
    'components' => array(
            'db' => require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../db_config.php'),
            'dba' => require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../dba_config.php'),
            'dbmobisite' => require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../dbmobisite_config.php'),
            'dbamobisite' => require(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../dbamobisite_config.php'),
    )
)
```

Now I changed :

```
$db = Yii::app()->getComponent('dbmobisite'); //wanted to use different db
$db->setActive(true); //changing it to active
$countries = Country::find()->orderBy('name')->all(); //but this still queries using "db" configuration not "dbmobisite" configuration.
```

I want to "dbmobisite" only for a single query. is it possible? if possible please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that the simplest solution is to create a new class extended by that and override getDb() method, such as:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class CountryOtherDb extends Country
{
      public function getDb()
      {
             return \Yii::$app->otherDb
      }
}
```